# Getting whitespace while reading XML using XMLTextReader

Tags: c#, .net, xml-parsing, xmltextreader

I am reading an XML using XMLTextReader in C#.net. The structure of XML is like below:

```
<root attr1="" attr2="">
    <element1>some value</element1>
    <element2>some value</element2>
</root>
```

After reding attributes, I shift control to element1. Code is as below:

```
reader.MoveToElement()
if(reader.ReadToDecedent("element1"))
{
    string val= reader.ReadInnerXML();
}
```

Now after reading this, reader shows whites space. Again I want to move to element1 and from there, using ReadToDecendent I want to move to element2. I cannot use MoveToContent() as I have to follow the same flow.

So how can I move to element1 after reader inner text?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using `XPathDocument` and the related classes? It would look like such:

```
var _xml = "<xml><elements><element1>some text</element1><element2>some more text</element2></elements></xml>";
var xPathDoc = new XPathDocument(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(_xml)));
var nav = xPathDoc.CreateNavigator();
var node = nav.SelectSingleNode("//element1");  // with xpath exp you can pick out specific tags
var innerText = node.Value;
```

Now if you just had element as the name of the tags instead of element1, element2,... you can iterate through all element tags:

```
var nodes = nav.Select("//element");  // selects all element tags
while(nodes.MoveNext()){
    //do something
}
```

This is probably a simpler way to query a xml doc. Plus, if you wanted tags that had a specific attribute, the xpath expression would be `//element[attr1=\"atrribute_value\"]`

Hope this helps